# eclipse is waiting forever to start liberty server

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-wdt

I'm using windows 7, eclipse neon.3, liberty server 17.0.0.1, WebSphere® Application Server Liberty Tools   2016.0.0.v20170505_1729

I have a probem when starting the liberty server from eclipse. The server is actually starting fine, but eclipse is  just showing the 'Starting'- status and never get confirmation that the server is actually started. After the predefined timeout, eclipse is giving up and stops the server.

If I start the server from command line, everythings works fine and eclipse confirmed that the server is running. Have tried both ibm sdk 8 and oracle.

What is actually the WDT (or eclipse) using for determing the server is started or not ?

Answer (score 1):

WDT is looking for this message from the server: CWWKF0011I: The server is ready to run a smarter planet.

Please check the following link to make sure you have not changed something in the server configuration that is causing the tools to miss the message:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/r_limitations.html

Comment: Yes, I have found a bug in WDT. After removing com.ibm.ws.logging.
console.log.level=OFF from my bootstrap.properties, then the WDT works as designed. It looks lik it's missing the console.log. Have rised an PMR for that.

Comment: Ups, after reading the link, it's just my issue, but I found it myself. I might be a good debugger ... :-)